# Having and Where in combination with Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have learned to use `HAVING` when I use `GROUP BY` instead of the `WHERE` clause and never encountered any problems with it. Today I saw this on a w3schools.com a SQL Learning Page:

```
SELECT Employees.LastName, COUNT(Orders.OrderID) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Employees ON Orders.EmployeeID = Employees.EmployeeID
WHERE LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller'
GROUP BY LastName
HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 25;
```

1. Why this should work?
2. When I should use this?

Comment: *"I have learned to use `HAVING` when I use `GROUP BY` instead of the `WHERE` clause"* You learned wrong. The `WHERE` is always allowed. The `HAVING` is for when you want to filter results based on an aggregate function, like `COUNT` in your query, it doesn't replace the `WHERE`. The `WHERE` is by far the more appropriate place for clauses that don't use aggregate functions (again, as demonstrated in the above).

Comment: couldnt I write HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 25 and (LastName = 'Davolio' OR LastName = 'Fuller') gives me the same result. In this case where would be redundant

Comment: You *could* but it's isn't advisable. I suspect that such a query would be less performant as well, as the RDBMS would aggregate *all* values of `LastName` and then filter, rather than filter and then aggregate. Meaning a table scan would be required (I haven't tested this, but the [`HAVING` is processed *after* the `GROUP BY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement) so it would seem logical that would occur).

Comment: Probably the optimizer is re-writing your query to implicitly use the discretely-valued predicates as an actual `WHERE` and bailing you out. As @Larnu (correctly) points out, you can do a great many things that you probably shouldn't do. Knowing how to tell the difference and not just plowing ahead "because it works" will serve you well.

Comment: ok thank you guys. that was of great help for me. Dig deeper into it myself.

Comment: Having a look at a *very* simple query, yes, it seems the optimiser is (as @paneerakbari puts it) "bailing you out", and it effectively propagates the clause `LastName IN ('Davolio','Fuller')` to the `WHERE` rather than in the `HAVING`, as it performs a seek and expects 18 rows, but I suspect in a more complex query, you might not be so lucky. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=cf1e30820e55c9d2aaa2a01994344ff3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `WHERE` and `HAVING` is central to when you should employ one vs the other, or even both in conjunction.

`HAVING` enables you to filer your result set based on an aggregate value. In your example, you are limiting the data returned by the query to just those rows that have an aggregate (`COUNT`) greater than 25. It is not possible to define this sort of predicate in a `WHERE` due to syntax constraints.

The `WHERE` keyword is used to define predicates for the query based on discrete (non-aggregate) values. In your example, the `WHERE` is limiting the result based on the LastName and FirstName values.

They are able to be used in conjunction with one another as valid syntax because they perform different (albeit very similar) operations that cannot be accomplished by the other in isolation. As for why one should use this, it's simply a matter of needing to limit a result set based on both aggregate and discrete conditions.